# Bootstrap 100% Height

Tags: twitter, twitter-bootstrap-3, row-height

I am creating a widget page using asp.net 4.0 and bootstrap which is going to be accessed across a variety of different screens so I need to have the main content responsive to grow/shrink based on the size of the screen.

My current code is similar to this -

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row header">
           HEADER ROW
        </div><!--/.row-->

        <div class="row">
         MAIN CONTENT 
        </div

        <footer>
           FOOTER GOES HERE
        </footer>

    </div><!--/.container-fluid-->
```

So the header and the footer will be 100px or 10% each and I want the main content to expand the height in between the header and footer.

How can I do this without specifying a height in pixels?

Thanks

Comment: I know from experience that without bootstrap, you need to give the `HTML` and `BODY` elements a height of `100%` before you can give it to your `wrapper` element, but I dont know if bootstrap changes those specs.

Comment: Did you search for the answer before posting this question?  This question and similar ones have been answered numerous times already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flex box for this.

```
div.wrapper {
  background:green;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
  flex: 0 1 100px;
}

div.main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

footer {
  border-top:1px solid black;
  flex: 0 1 100px;
}
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/tqaar3zr/2/

Comment: Hi- thanks for this but seems to be for the HTML/Body, where I just want the main content row to be height responsive. and the header and footer can be specified as 100px.

Comment: Did you try the solution? This works for entire-page structures like you gave me. If you can put the surrounding element's height as it should be, the flex-box solution still works. The center element is height-responsive, the others seem to 'stick' to the top and bottom of the page.

Comment: Sorry - looks different know like it hadn't loaded properly. Is there away which you could add a <div class="well"> to this row and that to expand 100% of the row height?

Comment: `display:flex` and `flex-flow:column` are the surrounding tags on any div you want the component inside, `flex: 1 1 auto` makes the height 100% relative to that so use that on your `well` classed `div` element. Play around with these a little and read the w3schools tutorial on flex-flow. Start with the display tutorial if you are not sure what that does as well.

Comment: PS: Please vote if this helped you and accept if it solved your original problem. And if you provide codes in JSFiddle next time its easier for us to help you.